# What is the difference between Ubuntu.Components and QtQuick?

Tags: application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt-creator

QtQuick 2.0

Ubuntu.Components 0.1

Are two common imports when developing applications for Ubuntu.

1. Are these classes? Can you import member functions this way? If yes, how can tell what member functions are available for importing?
2. Is there any reason why I should import QtQuick 1.x, or is it generally reasonable to assume that the latest version is what I should be using?
3. How do I tell what the latest version of either is?
4. Broadly Speaking; What functionality do these imports actually provide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. QtQuick and Ubuntu.Components are two different **namespaces** and [importing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-basics.html#import-statements) them gives access to several standards components such as Rectangle for QtQuick or UbuntuShape for Ubuntu.Components.
2. You always have to specify the version to import as several may have been installed on your system such as QtWebKit.experimental 1.0 and QtWebKit 3.0.

   Note that Ubuntu.Components require QtQuick 2.0 not 1.x
3. To know their versions, one possible way is to look at their [qmldir](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html) file.
4. The list of object types provided by both is too long to be listed here, so please visit the following links for a full reference:

   - QtQuick: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-qmltypereference.html
   - Ubuntu.Components: http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/Ubuntu.Components/